# Freeze top column (title columns)

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, express

In a node.js application: Is there a way to freeze the top row in a table, the title row, in the browser the way you can in Excel?

I suspect this is a .css style, but not sure how to do it. `fixed` "freezes" the entire table instead of just the top row in that as items appear in the non-visible part of the browser window, no vertical scroll bars appear so as to be able to see them. `sticky` appears to do nothing in this case.

.css

```
#one {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

app.js

```
<div className="row" id="one">
            <table className="table-hover">
                <thead>
```

Comment: Perhaps check out [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)

Comment: Thanks that does appear to fix the row. Unfortunately, when there are items that are added dynamically to the table underneath that are not visible in the window, the vertical scroll bars don't appear.

Comment: See edited original post.

Comment: Give me some time and I'll try to make a snippet for you c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution of an Excel-like fixed table head with [`position: sticky;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) (classy and a personal favorite). Click on the first row to make it sticky:

```css
th, td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
tr.sticks {
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.stuck th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="sticks" onclick='this.className = this.className == "sticks" ? "sticks stuck" : "sticks";'>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Amount </th>
            <th> Date </th>
            <th> Color </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

And here's a solution using JavaScript (less classy but with more usability). This one supports more than one row being stuck to the top. Again, click on a row to stick it:

```css
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
#table-head {
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
#table-head td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <thead id="table-head"></thead>
    <tbody id="table-body">
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
        <tr onclick="stick_it(this);">
            <td> A </td>
            <td> B </td>
            <td> C </td>
            <td> D </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table_head = document.getElementById("table-head");
    var table_body = document.getElementById("table-body");
    var stick_it = function(el) {
        var row_html = el.outerHTML.replace("stick_it(this);", "unstick_it(this);");
        el.remove();
        table_head.innerHTML += row_html;
        table.style.paddingTop = table_head.children.length * 104 + "px";
    }
    var unstick_it = function(el) {
        var row_html = el.outerHTML.replace("unstick_it(this);", "stick_it(this);");
        el.remove();
        table_body.innerHTML += row_html;
        table.style.paddingTop = table_head.children.length * 104 + "px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't get it to work for me in the context of node.js/express/react but your solution clearly works so I have to figure out how to port it. Thanks.